# Exception executing insert

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I would like to make an insert statement that operates in a bulk/set fashion instead of a singleton/RBAR.

I am encountering an exception with my SQL syntax and unable to fathom why.

```
public void Insert_tag(ArrayList key, ArrayList key_tag, String[] tag, String[] make_key, String fname, int fseq, ArrayList khannTag)throws Exception{
    PreparedStatement prep = Local.prepareStatement("delete from tagDB where fname=? and fseq=?;");
    prep.setString(1,fname);
    prep.setInt(2,fseq);
    prep.execute();

    String query = "insert into tagDB values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, 0, 0, ?, ?, ?)";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < key.size()-1 ; i++ ) {
        query = query.concat(",(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, 0, 0, ?, ?, ?)");
    }
    System.out.println(query);
    PreparedStatement prep3 = Local.prepareStatement(query); // <<<< Exception

    for(int n=0 ; n<key.size() ; n++) {
        prep3.setString(8*n+1, (String) key.get(n));
        prep3.setString(8*n+2, (String) key_tag.get(n));
        prep3.setString(8*n+3, (String) khannTag.get(n));
        prep3.setString(8*n+4, tag[n]);
        prep3.setString(8*n+5,make_key[n]);
        prep3.setString(8*n+6,fname);
        prep3.setInt(8*n+7,fseq);
        prep3.setInt(8*n+8,n);
    }

    prep3.executeUpdate();
    prep3.close();
    prep.close();
}
```

And, my log is here.

```
java.sql.SQLException: near ",": syntax error
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Why do many people tag SQL Server as well as MySql?

Comment: @Raj [Because they are suggested by the system, and users are lazy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005. The `VALUES(),()` construct you're trying to use was introduced in SQL Server 2008. So you're going to have to change the query you're building from this:

```
INSERT ... VALUES(), (), ();
```

To this:

```
INSERT ... VALUES();
INSERT ... VALUES();
INSERT ... VALUES();
```

Or:

```
INSERT ... SELECT
UNION ALL  SELECT
UNION ALL  SELECT 
...
```

Or look into SQLBulkCopy.

Or, you could upgrade, I suppose.

Comment: but... that you introduce is not bulk query... i mean it takes so many times.. isn't it? T^T

Comment: @ChangukShin Are you trying to solve your syntax error, or trying to make your code that doesn't work faster? Let's deal with one problem at a time, ok?

Comment: and i use jdk 1.6 (cause of OS X).

Comment: ah... i can insert each row at time. but it takes many time so i want to make it faster... i can show u last codes... i want to make you angry. sorry.

Comment: I think my jdk or something can't do my syntax, you said that.

Comment: @ChangukShin Your initial question complained about a syntax error. I was showing you how you can fix the syntax error. If you get your code working, and you want help making it faster, please ask a separate question.